# Stop Android Graph View from rounding the x-axis

Tags: android-graphview

I'm using graph view in my project and got it working just fine. However I don't like the x-axis values. The values I'm passing are 0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5...all the way to 23.5. I would like the graph to show every x-axis value on the grid and not rounded values of 0,3.4,6.9,10.3, 13.7 etc. Is there a way to force it to not round and use the x values provided?

Answer (score 0):

the labels are have fix positions and shows the exact value at this point. It seems, that you want to have the another count of labels or other positions. In the current GraphView version you can set set count of labels. When you configure it in the correct way, you should see labels in 0.5-steps.

Have a look at `GraphViewStyle#setNumHorizontalLabels`